# How can non-final fields be used in a anonymous class class if their value can change?

Tags: java, field, final, local-variables, anonymous-class

I asked this question before but I didn't get an appropriate answer.

**How can non-final fields be used in a anonymous class class if their value can change?**

```
class Foo{
    private int i;
    void bar(){
        i = 10
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable (){
            public void run (){
                System.out.println(i); //works fine
            }//end method run
        }//end Runnable
    }//end method bar
}//end class Foo
```

If the local variables which are used inside an anonymous class must be `final` to enable the compiler inlining their values inside the anonymous class code like that:

**Before:**

```
public class Access1 {
  public void f() {
    final int i = 3;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(i);
        }//end method run
    };//end anonymous class
  }//end method f
}//end class Access1
```

**After:**

```
public class Access1 {
    public Access1() {}//end constructor

    public void f() {
        Access1$1 access1$1 = new Access1$1(this);
    }//end method f
}//end class Access1
```

And

```
class Access1$1 implements Runnable {
    Access1$1(Access1 access1) {
        this$0 = access1;
    }//end constructor

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(3);
    }//end method run
    private final Access1 this$0;
}//end class Access1$1
```

Then **how can the compiler inline a value of a non-final field?**

Comment: The compiler can't inline fields that are not compile time constants. Are you sure you decompiled the right code?

Comment: @Joni I'm not inlining a field value above. I'm just comparing between inline a local variable value and the way an anonymous class uses a non-final value of a field (which I don't know yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a big difference between a method call's local variable (which must be `final` to be accessible to an inner class), and an instance's private data members.

The inner class has access to the containing instance, and to all of the members of that instance, `final` or not. There's no need for them to be final, because they're referenced through (in your case) `Foo.this`. So when accessing your `i` member, the inner class is really accessing `Foo.this.i`, it's just that `Foo.this` (like `this`) can be implied if a reference is unambiguous without it.

But the anonymous class's code can't access local variables that way, because they aren't (of course) instance members of the containing class. So instead, the compiler does a very funny thing: It creates an instance member of the *anonymous* class for each `final` local variable, and when creating the instance of the anonymous class, it initializes those members with the values of the local variables.

Let's watch it do that:

```
public class InnerEx {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        new InnerEx().test("hi");
    }

    private void test(String arg) {
        final String localVar = arg;

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(localVar);
            }
        };
        r.run();
    }
}
```

When compiled, we get `InnerEx.class` and `InnerEx$1.class`. If we decompile `InnerEx$1.class`, we see this:

```
class InnerEx$1 implements java.lang.Runnable {
  final java.lang.String val$localVar;

  final InnerEx this$0;

  InnerEx$1(InnerEx, java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: aload_1       
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$0:LInnerEx;
       5: aload_0       
       6: aload_2       
       7: putfield      #2                  // Field val$localVar:Ljava/lang/String;
      10: aload_0       
      11: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      14: return        

  public void run();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: aload_0       
       4: getfield      #2                  // Field val$localVar:Ljava/lang/String;
       7: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      10: return        
}
```

Note the instance member called `val$localVar`, which is the instance member created to stand in for the local variable in the call to `InnerEx#test`.

Comment: So in my case, the anonymous class I created inside class 'Foo' can refer to the **private** field 'i' without any constraints using the code Foo.this.i? Considering the anonymous class is separated in another file and a reference of it is used inside the enclosing class (as it's the case with the code I wrote in my question), shouldn't private members of the enclosing class be NOT accessible to the anonymous class (which became in a separate file and has reference to its enclosing class)? I'm sorry I know it's a little bit confusing :D

Comment: @KareemMesbah: *"So...the anonymous class I created inside class 'Foo' can refer to the private field 'i' without any constraints using the code Foo.this.i?"* Yes, but the `Foo.this.` part of that is optional. `i` and `Foo.this.i` are exactly the same thing (you only need the `Foo.this.` part if `i` on its own is ambiguous to the compiler). *"Considering the anonymous class is created in another file..."* No it isn't, the anonymous class is created in the `Foo.java` file, right there in your `bar` method. It *implements* an interface defined elsewhere, but the class is defined within `Foo`.

Comment: Could you please check section: **final local variables** on http://goo.gl/xHqksx? that's what I meant by *"the anonymous class is separated in another file"*. Isn't this true?

Comment: @KareemMesbah: I'm not following some random blind link off-site. If you're referring to a section in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) or one of the Java tutorials, refer to it directly. It's also best practice to actually quote what you're referring to. But again: No, the anonymous class is created in your `Foo.java`, inside your `bar` method, where you say `= new Runnable() { ... };`.

Comment: I'm referring to the part of my question from the word **Before** — classes Access1 and Access1$1. Isn't this what we get after decompiling with the JAD?

Comment: @KareemMesbah: Again, there's a big difference between an object instance member (`i` in your `Foo`) and a local variable in a method call (`i`, a local variable in `Access1`'s `foo` method).

Comment: I'm sorry but again I know there is a difference. I'm just trying to understand. So your answer in other words should be: because we can refer to a field using a reference to the enclosing class (implicitly or explicitly), but we cannot access a local variable using a reference of the enclosing class and that's why the compiler requires local variables to be final to inline their values while using the reference to the enclosing class to access its fields. Am I get it right?

Comment: @KareemMesbah: Essentially. The compiler doesn't inline the values of the final local variables; instead (and this is much more surprising), it creates instance members on the anonymous class. I've added to the answer to show that.

Comment: Couldn't it just create instance members on the anonymous class and initialize them with the values of the local variables without requiring the local variables being final?

Comment: @KareemMesbah: It *could* have been designed that way, but then people would get really confused, because we have two independent things: The local variable, and the inner class's member with (effectively) the same name. Changing one wouldn't change the other. Imagine the resulting bugs, esp. if you think in terms of multiple inner classes interacting... So they went with `final`, since it wipes away that entire class of problems.

Comment: @KareemMesbah: You're welcome -- I learned things answering this, which is always fun!